# How to interpret complex transaction data on cardano blockchain

Tags: transaction, blockfrost

for many of you this may seem as a complete noob question, but I am as many new to this world and can need a hand with this question.
I am currently looking at some random transactions of some NFTs and I am interested to follow how the the funds moved and what was exchanged. I am currently looking at an complex example of inputs and outputs for this transaction:  `0e8bea7ba9c1041d2561df7814be45d29a755d7bd0ea55127e0b92589fef50dd`.

I know that one NFT (`d5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756432`) was transferred with this transaction. But it seems like that there are also other assets transferred.

I am interested in getting to know what price was paid for this NFT for this transaction, but the input data throws me off... If there were multiple assets exchanged how can they all come from different input addresses, but end up in only two addresses in the output. Also can there be any conclusions drawn for the NFT price being made from the 3000000000 lovelace int the output?

For reference here the data that I look at currently. The data comes from Blockfrost's transaction endpoint

These are the inputs:

```
{'addr1q8drvrh7zd9xcenkkatr72zew7s4zxaexz3knm25nvk9sdwz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60ms7nqqqy': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1600000',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '16a2a21a7ed8a67c5254eda1f8d6041021b53f49ef53e18e3e572546456e7468656f7332353034303941'}]},
 'addr1q8dyg95ylje8ae95r2s2l5tyl0jtswnnpgc3h0j7e4e27pwz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60msq725nl': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1481480',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '1131301ad4b3cb7deaddbc8f03f77189082a5738c0167e177223309743617264616e6f4269747331383237'}]},
 'addr1q9cfmycakxay3y5qhn506eune2pa8z4ewm96w8a75gdkdqkz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60mscy0j02': {'amount': [{'quantity': '200850834540',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '2535',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'cfee97ff8359f07a0a395a72b424bc6e030503390d864b86d4e0ecf84b41495a454e'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756432'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '25',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd894897411707efa755a76deb66d26dfd50593f2e70863e1661e98a07370616365636f696e73'}]},
 'addr1q9ec78mw889j7y8jj7lvh026mef78tv4x0qgvgnpwh0lym7z08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60msg69x63': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1444443',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a6e7963'}]},
 'addr1q9nmqf9tftv0ptvyshdeetchz7enqgu6m2v04gctgr62pgkz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60ms8yydm5': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1481480',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a62616e6b746865756e62616e6b6564'}]},
 'addr1q9wt3x052yktn74ej03u4unst3lmzxywhac2kcjnqahzlm7z08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60msla4g7q': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1500000',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '330434765',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '1dd1a7dde0e1e82761325ee5f4719d0d4b7c24dfba77d9bee01eed4b4d454f57'}]},
 'addr1qygw382y23qrk6w0rwpu5mecje4ej6eqhpqz2qsnphhnhfxz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60msug9lhc': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1444443',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a6c6f6e646f6e'}]},
 'addr1qyh0p0lfwx4pu8yfvh6sz0rrrhhcxhlvz8dehrzp6njrk27z08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60ms2krpxp': {'amount': [{'quantity': '1481480',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756436333930'}]}}
```

and these are the outputs:

```
{'addr1q8dyg95ylje8ae95r2s2l5tyl0jtswnnpgc3h0j7e4e27pwz08dtlwcmxp6k0z4peenj7a6px4mm84lqlwcnvsdg60msq725nl': {'amount': [{'quantity': '197857877370',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '3148145',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '1131301ad4b3cb7deaddbc8f03f77189082a5738c0167e177223309743617264616e6f4269747331383237'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '16a2a21a7ed8a67c5254eda1f8d6041021b53f49ef53e18e3e572546456e7468656f7332353034303941'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '330434765',
                                                                                                                         'unit': '1dd1a7dde0e1e82761325ee5f4719d0d4b7c24dfba77d9bee01eed4b4d454f57'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '2535',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'cfee97ff8359f07a0a395a72b424bc6e030503390d864b86d4e0ecf84b41495a454e'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756432'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756436333930'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '25',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'd894897411707efa755a76deb66d26dfd50593f2e70863e1661e98a07370616365636f696e73'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a62616e6b746865756e62616e6b6564'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a6c6f6e646f6e'},
                                                                                                                        {'quantity': '1',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a6e7963'}]},
 'addr1qyk5ncxm5d4x0gzwx8k63jev36a00a4yrelw2lrld42m9lxe3t9p2xq8fjyyn8e87aqg7tpajpdhpkyn8dhszr35kvvsgg0ml6': {'amount': [{'quantity': '3000000000',
                                                                                                                         'unit': 'lovelace'}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. UTXO model allows for transactions with 1 to 1, 1 to n, n to 1, or n to n inputs to outputs. Additionally, many addresses can be (and often are) derived from the same set of master keys. This means your single wallet may contain multiple UTXOs sitting in multiple addresses, all controlled by you.
2. When you want to send assets, wallet software(s) will employ some kind of UTXO-selection algorithm to automatically select which UTXOs to use in the transaction, such that everything you want to send gets sent, without having to use every single UTXO in your wallet. Naturally, some of the assets in input UTXOs are still yours, and so they are sent back to the origin address or another "change" address in your wallet. This usually involves consolidating all of your "change" assets into a single UTXO that is sent back to you, appearing like any other tx-output.
3. Since we do not yet have standards in terms of DEXs and oracles, it is hard to tell what price was paid for an NFT just by looking at the inputs and outputs of a transaction. It may be possible to do this by analyzing the specific smart contract (assuming it is open source) that the transaction(s) interacted with, but this would be a more involved process that just querying one or two transaction IO's.

Perhaps someone else who is adept at analyzing specific smart contract utility can help out with this last part.

Comment: thanks a lot for this explanation! really appreciate it!